# classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I'm currently working on an app that has got some face detection in it. i'm using android's FaceDetector class and one of it's methods. i'm getting the frame from the previewframe callback but the format is YuvImage. i need it to be a bitmap for the facedetection to work. The problem is when i run the program there's an error saying classnotfoundexception with regard to the yuvimage. i've imported the yuvimage class and there's no errors in the source file. why can't the yuvimage class be found?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is a activity or service  must and should mention it in android manifest file

Comment: why must it be declared in the manifest? the yuvimage as in the class android.graphics.yuvimage should be available. it's as if the class is not on the classpath or buildpath for the project.

Comment: yuvimage is only available since Froyo+, you're on that version, right?